# Meteor - Updating user profile inside callback

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to update a user profile inside a callback, but I keep gettings the same error. Already tried multiple approaches.. Any help would be great. Thanks!

> Exception in callback of async function: Error: Invalid modifier.
>   Modifier must be an object.

```
        let user = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.wallets.address": d.Address});
        let wallets = user.profile.wallets;
        wallets[0].amount = d.Amount;

        Meteor.users.update(user._id, {$set: {'profile.wallets': wallets}});
```

Comment: I think you need to put quotes around `"$set"`

Comment: still have the same error message @Mikkel

Comment: Quotes aren't needed on keys unless they are nested. The `$set`, `$inc` etc... operators don't need to be quoted.

Comment: I suggest doing `console.log({$set: {'profile.wallets': wallets}}) in the debugger to make sure that expression actually results in an object. It really should but that's the modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this:

```
let profile = user.profile
profile.wallets = wallets
Meteor.users.update(user._id, {$set: {profile: profile}})
```

Because maybe the modifier can't be a dotted path

Comment: A key name can contain a dotted path if quoted. There's something else going on here.